# What is the meaning of difference in this sentence ?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033870/synopsis)

> Brigid O'Shaughnessy asks Spade if the Falcon had been real, and he'd
>   gotten the entire $10,000, would it have made a **difference**.

What is the meaning of difference in this sentence ?

Comment: The sentence is very poorly written. IMDB reviews are a terrible source for decent writing in English. This is reported speech, but the writer omits quotation marks. The sentence should read: _Brigid O'Shaughnessy asks Spade:  "If the Falcon had been real, and he'd gotten the entire $10,000, would it have made a difference?"_ Consult your dictionary to learn the meaning of _difference_. It is used here in an entirely ordinary sense.

Answer (score 1):

"Would it have made a difference" here could be translated simply into "would it have changed anything about the situation".